# Is there any memory restriction chrome.storage.sync.set in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am saving some bulk data in chrome browser local storage using

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({'data': request.data }, function() {
            console.log('Settings saved');
        });.
```

when data gets bigger to certain level, data is not getting saved, Is there any memory restriction.

Comment: You should check `chrome.runtime.lastError` within the callback to see the exact failure reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a limit, it is laid out quite clearly [in the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#properties).

Looks like for `chrome.storage.sync` the maximum total storage size is 800kB [0].

For `chrome.storage.local` the maximum is 5MB [0], unless you request unlimitedStorage so this API should be more useful to you.

[0] [Source](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#properties)

Comment: The last part of the answer is incorrect. The maximum limit for `chrome.storage.local` is not 40MB, it is 5MB, and can be unlimited if you add the `unlimitedStorage` permission.

Comment: It would help to quote the limits (as is at the current date) in the answer.

Comment: It is currently ~102KB total for sync (from my recall). The docs have changed and this information is no longer visible online.

@Xan Any idea where I can find these values?

I am also interested in MAX_WRITE_OPERATIONS_PER_MINUTE limit and same for read.